# Определить цену при большом количестве условий

Tags: excel

В таблице содержатся разные типы данных, например:

Форма: квартат, круг, треугольник итд

Цвет: красный, желтый, черный, синий

Вес: 1, 2

Размер: 1, 2, 3, 4

и т.д.

Необходимо проверить все эти условия и вывести значение:

Если квадрат, красный, 2, 4 то его цена 100руб

Если квадрат, черный, 2, 4 то цена 102руб
...

и т.д. для всех возможных вариаций.

Подскажите возможные пути решения. Формула "Если" получается слишком громоздкой и превышает все пределы.

Дополнение:

Данные находятся в таблице по столбцам. т.е первый столбец - форма, второй - цвет, третий - размер, и еще другие переменные. Последний столбец по идее должен содержать цену соответствующей конфигурации. Цена находится на соседнем листе в таблице где прописаны все варианты и их стоимость. В целом не проблема посмотреть в соседний лист, найти нужную конфигурацию, посмотреть цену и вписать вручную, но хотелось бы автоматизировать.

Кроме вышеперечисленных параметров у каждой конфигурации есть свой серийный номер, физический адрес итд. Но это не влияет на конечную стоимость. В таблице около тысячи серийных номеров.

[image: таблица данных, пример]

[image: зависимость цены, пример]

---

Данные находятся в таблице по столбцам. т.е первый столбец - форма, второй - цвет, третий - размер, и еще другие переменные.
 Последний столбец по идее должен содержать цену соответствующей конфигурации.
 Цена находится на соседнем листе в таблице где прописаны все варианты и их стоимость. В целом не  проблема посмотреть в соседний лист, найти нужную конфигурацию, посмотреть цену и вписать вручную, но хотелось бы автоматизировать.

прошу прощения, написал с другого автора.
кроме вышеперечисленных параметров у каждой конфигурации есть свой серийный номер, физический адрес итд. но это не влияет на конечную стоимость. в таблице около тысячи серийных номеров.

Comment: Пожалуй... покажите ваш громоздкий если - может что посоветуем. Выйти из положения... возможно поможет вспомогательная таблица и табличные ф-ции, например ВПР. Лист или столбцы с вспомогательной таблицей можно скрыть. Суть... нужно сгенерировать верно "ключ", и составить таблицу ключ-результат. Тогда можно упростить если. Если задача "нелинейная" или дерево если имеет множество нелинейных ветвлений - то никак.

Comment: Покажите пример расположения данных. Расскажите, как связана цена с набором значений

Comment: >> *есть свой серийный номер. Но это не влияет на конечную стоимость* +++Как это? Если в строке уникальный номер, то и цену можно подтянуть по нему, не нужно просматривать все данные.

Comment: В таблице цен нет привязки к серийному номеру, цена зависит от параметров типа "форма, цвет, итд" . Попробую воспользоваться ВПР из советов ниже.

Answer (score 0):

Верхняя таблица - туда подтягивать данные, нижняя - исходная с ценами. Если так, то *ВПР* никак не поможет.

Нижнюю таблицу привести к нормальному виду плоской таблицы - снять объединение ячеек и прописать значения в каждой строке.

Вы не показали наименования столбцов, поэтому диапазоны в формулах "на глаз".

```
=СУММЕСЛИМН(ИНДЕКС(Лист1!$D:$F;ПОИСКПОЗ(вес;Лист1!$D1:$F1););Лист1!$A:$A;B2;Лист1!$B:$B;C2;Лист1!$C:$C;D2)
=СУММПРОИЗВ(ИНДЕКС(Лист1!$D:$F;ПОИСКПОЗ(вес;Лист1!$D1:$F1000););--(B2=Лист1!$A$2:$A$1000);--(C2=Лист1!$B$2:$B$1000);--(D2=Лист1!$C$2:$C$1000))
```

Столбец *D:F* - цена, столбец с ценой определяется по весу. В условиях - сравнение параметров. Условия можно добавлять.

*СУММЕСЛИМН* работает быстрее, но в старой версии *Excel-2003* ее нет. там можно использовать *СУММПРОИЗВ*.

В *СУММЕСЛИМН* можно указывать диапазоны целых столбцов - функция умеет определять используемый диапазон. В *СУММПРОИЗВ* так делать нельзя - будет просчитываться весь столбец.